# How to assign 4 fixed numbers randomly to 4 variables in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need to assign 4 different variables with 3 incorrect and 1 correct answer randomly.

I tried using arrays but did'nt get it right

Comment: post what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to the question, reopen and reformulate it (preferably with your code, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure that a similar question has not already been answered. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
// Create an array of elements to shuffle
const answers = ['incorrect', 'incorrect', 'incorrect', 'correct'];

// Shuffle the answers
for (let i = answers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [answers[i], answers[j]] = [answers[j], answers[i]];
}

// Display the results
console.log(answers[0], answers[1], answers[2], answers[3]);
```